# Java - memory mapped file and flushing

Tags: java, operating-system, nio, memory-mapped-files

Given that I am using a memory-mapped file in Java, with an underlying page sie of 4KB, are there any guarantees about when the flush (page synch) will be performed with respect to writes?

For instance: If I write 100 bytes to the page A, will those 100 bytes always be reflected fully or can O/S synch at an arbitrary time, let's say after writing just 10 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The guarantee, or rather the lack of one, is explicitly stated in the Javadoc:

> The content of a mapped byte buffer can change at any time, for example if the content of the corresponding region of the mapped file is changed by this program or another. Whether or not such changes occur, and when they occur, is operating-system dependent and therefore unspecified.